# Code in separate cells causes a kernel crash

Tags: bugs, memory, system-performance

**Bug introduced in 11.2**

---

If I put the following code in separate cells the Kernel crashes (dies). If I put them together in the same cell it works fine. Version 11.3.0 for Windows.

```
data = Table[{t, E^(-2 π 13.2 0.01 t) Cos[2 π 13.2 t]}, {t, 0, 40 - 1/100., 1/10000.}];
(* end of cell 1*)

ClearAll[f];
f[data_] := Module[{a, b, c},
   a = 2 data;
   b = 3 data;
   c = 4 data;
   {a, b, c}
   ];
(* end of cell 2*)

{a, b, c} = f[data];
(* end of cell 3*)
```

Any thoughts? Does it happen to others?

Comment: Hi, Hugh. Unfortunately for you (not for me ;) ), I cannot reproduce that with version 11.3 on macOS.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for trying. Happens repeatedly for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It's a weird error indeed. No idea what to do apart from switching off and on again... =/

Comment: I can reproduce this in 11.3 for Windows 7.

Comment: @ulvi Glad to hear I'm not the only one. Thanks for doing this. Tricky problem to avoid though.

Comment: What happens if you do `$HistoryLength=0`?

Comment: @CarlWoll That seems to fix the problem. A reasonable solution. Thanks.

Comment: @ilian I think it is the same problem but its not to do with RandomInteger. Its all about the suggestions bar. We could do with a better title. I think mine is a bit more general since the suggestions bar appears after a cell. How do we get an easily found title?

Comment: Yes, I agree the title could be improved. But apart from that, the other question has a simpler code example and a more complete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that using a semicolon to suppress *large* output doesn't actually prevent Mathematica from storing the *large* output. In particular, we have the following from the documentation:

> $expr_1; expr_2;$ returns value `Null`. If it is given as input, the resulting output will not be printed. `Out[n]` will nevertheless be assigned to be the value of $expr_2$.

Even though you are suppressing the output of `data` and `{a,b,c}`, their values are still being stored in `Out` when you put the expressions into separate cells. Apparently the storage of `data` causes Mathematica to exceed your available memory. The workaround is simple. Either use `$HistoryLength=0`, or terminate your cells with something like `; ;` or `; 1;`. With the latter method, Mathematica will store `Null` or `1` as the output of the cell, and not `data`.

Comment: `MaxMemoryUsed[]` never goes above 150MB. Even if we assume the last cell needs another 2GB of memory (surely overkill), still doesn't explain the problem in a system with 32GB RAM.

Comment: ulvi has added the comment that I was observing. Something else is happening or the the data memory size is being multiplied up excessively. Do you know enough to state that setting `$HistoryLength=0` will solve the problem?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Hugh It's not about the output size being large, but the issue can be reliably worked around by disabling the Suggestions bar. Changing the history length etc. work simply because they prevent the Suggestions bar from seeing the last result and trying to operate on it.