# Kernel crash with RandomInteger

Tags: bugs, crash, predictive-interface

**Bug introduced in 11.2**

---

I am using RandomInteger to create sorted test data in the following way:

```
lists = Sort /@ RandomInteger[10000, {10, 200000}];
```

With Mathematica 11.3, the kernel crashes on me if I evaluate the line above in the front a couple of times. The crash occurs on both the Windows and OS X versions of Mathematica.
I could not reproduce the bug with Mathematica 11.2.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with version 11.3 on macOS. Maybe the dimension of `lists` were greater when you tried? Then it could be that both results were stored in the history and blast the amount of available memory. Try to set `$HistoryLength = 0` or end your input cell with `;Null;` instead of `;`. The latter should store only `Null` instead of the value of `lists` in the history.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with version 11.3 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I too cannot reproduce that crash with `11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)` on OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: The `;Null;` trick seems to fix it, so it is probably related to the history.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug that can be worked around by [disabling](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/145) the Suggestions bar.

Given the input, it tries several operations in the background (wrapped in [`TimeConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeConstrained.html)) and one of these -- a call to [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) -- happens to crash when interrupted.

The reason `$HistoryLength = 0` or ending the input cell with `;Null;` works is that it prevents the Suggestions bar from seeing the input.

This is another [instance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172428/code-in-separate-cells-causes-a-kernel-crash/172433) of the same bug.

Comment: Disabling the suggestions bar fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Now that I have switched on the suggestion bar for the first time within 5 years, I can also reproduce the error... ^^ Many thanks for the clarification!