# Memory issue of SparseArray between Notebook window and Wolfram Documentation window

Tags: memory, sparse-arrays

Recently I'm trying creating a 80000 x 80000 sparse array in Mathematica, and I discovered a strange thing when using `SparseArray[]`.

Code: `s = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1}, {80000, 80000}]`

When I run this code in Wolfram Documentation window (find an example randomly, and replace it with this code, then run), the memory usage of `WolframKernel` almost remains the same. However, when I run that code in Notebook window, `WolframKernel`'s memory usage increases greatly up to ~40 GB, and when that happens, other variables in this Notebook are erased.

I'm wondering what's the difference between the two environment, and is a 80000 x 80000 sparse array in Mathematica, with few specified elements,  really takes up to over 1GB?

The version of Mathematica is 11.2.0.0, and the OS is macOS 10.13.4.

Comment: On my computer it works well. However, it is possible that your machine under certain conditions performs unpacking of the `SparseArray`. I'm not expert in this but try looking at discussion under [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148112/34848) thread.

Comment: See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172428/12558) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172641/12558). This is probably due to the suggestions bar. Try turning it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This undesirable behavior is caused by the [Suggestions bar](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframPredictiveInterface.html) and can be avoided by [turning it off](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/145).

Comment: This solves my problem. It is the fault of the Suggestions bar.